# I want to add certain effects into my webpage, for which I am unable to get my code correct

Tags: jquery

Here is the HTML for my page :

```
<div id="container">

       <div id="lineandbutton">
                         <div class="verticalline" style="display:none;"></div>
                   <div id="iwanimate" style="display:none;">
                         <div id="iwabutton">
                            <img src="siteimages/iwabutton.png" height="110px" width="110px">
                         </div>
                   </div>
       </div>
       <div id="titlesonly">
                       <div class="leftcontainer">
                                <div class="projects" style="display:none;">
                                <p id="projectstext"> <h2><a href="commercial/index.html" class="transition">PROJECTS</a></h2> </p>
                                </div>
                       </div>       
                       <div class="rightcontainer">
                                <div class="company"style="display:none;">
                                <p id="projectstext"> <h2><a href="thecompany.html" class="transition">COMPANY</a></h2> </p>
                                </div>
                       </div>
           </div>
```

Now , first I wanted to slidedown the verticalline and fadein the iwabutton, then click the iwabutton to reveal the Projects and Company titles. I got this effect correctly by putting in the following code into the head section :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".verticalline").slideDown("slow", "linear", function () {
        $("#iwanimate").fadeIn(2000);
    });
    $("#iwabutton").click(function () {
        $(".projects").fadeIn(2500);
        $(".company").fadeIn(2500);
    });
});
</script>
```

Now, I want the Project and Company titles to fadeout when one of them is clicked and the vertical line and iwabutton to move 289px to the left, the iwabutton should then go down by 100px and scale down to 55px and the corresponding link should open with the current page fading out and next page fading in slowly.

I wrote the code as follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                                $(document).ready(function() {
                                    $("a.transition").click(function(event){
                                        event.preventDefault();
                                        $("#titlesonly").fadeOut("slow",function(){$("#lineandbutton").animate({right:'289px',"slow",function(){$(#iwabutton").animate({bottom: '-=100px'}, "slow",function(){("#iwanimate").animate({height:'55px',width:'55px'});
                                        linkLocation = this.href;
                                        $("body").fadeout("slow",redirectPage);
                                        });
                                        function redirectPage() {
                                        window.location = linkLocation;
                                        }

                                       });
                                </script>
```

I got my first effect right, but the second effect doesn't seem to work out. can anyone please help me out? I would be very much grateful.

This piece of code gets the page transition effect correctly but I am unable to move the verticalline and iwabutton.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                                $(document).ready(function() {
                                    $("body").css("display", "none");

                                    $("body").fadeIn("slow");

                                    $("a.transition").click(function(event){
                                        event.preventDefault();
                                        linkLocation = this.href;
                                        $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);      
                                    });

                                    function redirectPage() {
                                        window.location = linkLocation;
                                    }
                                });
                                </script>
```

Comment: Please define "doesn't seem to work". What exactly happens when you click? What happens when you simplify the effect by removing some of the features?

Comment: Can you clean up your code and post what you have on JSFiddle?

Comment: You can see it at http://iwarchitects.com/test2

Answer (score 1):

Tidying the monster line into `.promise().then().then()...` form, I get :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.transition").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#titlesonly").fadeOut("slow").promise(function() {
            return $("#lineandbutton").animate({right:'289px'}, "slow").promise();
        }).then(function() {
            return $("#iwabutton").animate({bottom: '-=100px'}, "slow").promise();
        }).then(function() {
            return $("#iwanimate").animate({height:'55px', width:'55px'}).promise();
        });
        var linkLocation = this.href;
        $("body").fadeOut("slow", function() {
            window.location = linkLocation;
        });
    });
});
```

You've now got got a *managable* chain, which avoids a [pyramid of doom](http://tritarget.org/blog/2012/11/28/the-pyramid-of-doom-a-javascript-style-trap/).

However, I expect you want :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.transition").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var linkLocation = this.href;
        $("#titlesonly").fadeOut("slow").promise(function() {
            return $("#lineandbutton").animate({right:'289px'}, "slow").promise();
        }).then(function() {
            return $("#iwabutton").animate({bottom: '-=100px'}, "slow").promise();
        }).then(function() {
            return $("#iwanimate").animate({height:'55px', width:'55px'}).promise();
        }).then(function() {
            return $("body").fadeOut("slow").promise();
        }).then(function() {
            window.location = linkLocation;
        });
    });
});
```

Whether or not it will work is another matter. It depends on how well your HTML/CSS are constructed.

Comment: This is probably your best bet, as the fadeOut and fadeIn function's second argument (Which you set as redirectPage) executes when the animation starts, and not when it is complete like it says in the jQuery documentation. The promise function that Beetroot is using makes sure that all animations are complete before the next method is executed. +1

Comment: I am glad to learn about the promise() and then(), but still, the effect isn't working. You can check it at

http://iwarchitects.com/test2

Comment: The animation didn't execute before the page transition

Comment: The #titlesonly is fading out properly, but the animations afterthat are not getting executed......

Comment: Are you using the 2nd version?

Comment: yes. In the first version, the whole page is getting faded out, whereas in 2nd version, the first effect : #titlesonly is getting faded out.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the javascript is correct so try checking the HTML/CSS. For example, are the would-be animated elements all absolutely/relatively positioned? If not, their positions will not animate.

Comment: the mistake seems to be in the CSS. After the #titlesonly gets faded out, the #lineandbutton div is giving a jerk. 

The #lineandbutton, #iwanimate, and #titlesonly aren't styled in the CSS. I am trying to put them properly, but can you please help me get these three div's properly?

Comment: does it have to be only absolute/relative only? I was unable to fix the CSS .. :(

Comment: You just need to keep working at it. Try #lineandbutton absolute and everything inside it relative (ie relative to #lineandbutton). As far as I can tell, double wrapping the button in two divs in unnecessary - one or even no wrapping divs should do - just position the button itself.  You might also like to try animating #lineandbutton with something like `animate({left:'200px', marginLeft:0, "slow")` (200px is a guess), to cater for different screen widths.